# PayPal IPN sends multiple notifications hours after payment completed

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

In the IPN docs there is this line:

> To handle the possibility of transmission and receipt delays or failures, the IPN 
>   message service implements a retry mechanism that resends messages at various intervals 
>   until you acknowledge that the message has successfully been received.

IPN is sending the same notification 9 times... What do I need to send back? There are no errors in my script. If I use the IPN simulator I get the following message:

> IPN sent successfully

It would seem then that the simulator can tell the message is being sent correctly but the real notifier can't?

I am using sandbox if that makes any difference?

Do I need to print anything upon receipt of the notification?

Comment: we can acknowledge the PayPal with empty response after processing the post data as header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");. So no more responses will come in future.

Answer (score 12):

No need to worry about the multiple notification. First send back the IPN message then process it. While processing check the check that txn_id has not been previously processed. If it is already processed, it is a duplicate IPN message from the Paypal and you can ignore the processing.
For more info refer the pdf file:
[IPNGuide.pdf](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf)

**EDIT:**
Do I need to print anything upon receipt of the notification?
No need to print anything but if you want to log the details you can log them. 
From the pdf file I mentioned above(Page number 10)

> **Your listener must respond to each message, whether or not you intend
>   to do anything with it.**  If you do not respond, PayPal assumes that
>   the message was not received and resends the  message. PayPal
>   continues to resend the message periodically until your listener sends
>   the  correct message back, although the interval between resent
>   messages increases each time. The  message can be resent for up to
>   four days. This resend algorithm can lead to situations in which
>   PayPal resends the IPN message while  you are sending back the
>   original message. In this case, you should send your response again, 
>   to cover the possibility that PayPal did not actually receive your
>   response the first time. You  should also ensure that you do not
>   process the transaction associated with the message twice. **IMPORTANT:
>   PayPal expects to receive a response to an IPN message within 30
>   seconds.  Your listener should not perform time-consuming operations,
>   such as creating  a process, before responding to the IPN message**

See page number 19-20
Your listener software must

- Wait for an HTTP post from PayPal.
- Create a request that contains exactly the same IPN variables and values in the same order, 
  preceded with cmd=_notify-validate.
- Post the request to paypal.com or sandbox.paypal.com, depending on whether you 
  are going live or testing your listener in the Sandbox.
- Wait for a response from PayPal, which is either VERIFIED or INVALID.
- If the response is VERIFIED, perform the following checks:
- Confirm that the payment status is Completed. PayPal sends IPN    messages for pending and denied payments as well; do not ship until     the payment has cleared.
- Use the transaction ID to verify that the transaction has not    already been processed,  which prevents duplicate transactions from    being processed.
- Typically, you store transaction IDs in a database so that you know    you are only  processing unique transactions.
- Validate that the receiver’s email address is registered to you.    This check provides additional protection against fraud.
- Verify that the price, item description, and so on, match the    transaction on your website. This check provides additional    protection against fraud.
- If the verified response passes the checks, take action based on the value of the txn_type 
  variable if it exists; otherwise, take action based on the value of the reason_code 
  variable.
- If the response is INVALID, save the message for further investigation

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am doing everything that is asked. I return the IPN variables in order with _notify-validate, it is the first thing my script does. I get the VERIFIED response. You say I don't need to worry about the multiple notifications. This is being rolled out to several thousand clients. The difference between 1 notification and 9 notifications will be about 200k discarded notifications a week.. not a massive deal in the scheme of things but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Damodaran we can acknowledge the PayPal with empty response after processing the post data as `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`. So no more responses will come in future.

Answer (score 3):

You've got something going on with your IPN script that's causing it to fail a lot.  This could be happening at the very bottom of the script so everything you expect to see happen does happen, but then a 500 error gets sent back to PayPal.

Have you checked your PayPal IPN History to see what it's showing there?  You'll probably see lots of errors.  Also, you'll want to check your web server logs to see the error that's happening when that script is hit.

It could be something that only happens with certain orders.  For example, I often see people doing database updates or something similar and a name like O'Reilly breaks their script because they didn't handle the apostrophe correctly.

Looking at your web server logs should show you where the error occurred and then you can run some tests to help figure out the problem.  I like to create a basic HTML form, set the action to my IPN listener, and then add hidden fields that match what I expect to get in an IPN.  That way you can load it up in a browser and post various values to it directly which allows you to see the result on screen.  Just keep in mind that if you're testing this way the IPN won't be verified since it didn't come from PayPal, so you'll need to make sure your code is setup to handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to PayPal the IPN was received correctly after processing the response data as

```
public function yourIpnHandler(){
    //response verification and processing goes here


    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
}
```

After getting an empty 200 response, PayPal will not send more responses as it understand that response is delivered successfully to ipn-handler.